# CKEditor submit value empty (no ajax)

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

I have a problem with the [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com). I downloaded the current version and included it to my form as follows:

```
<form action="/news.php?frame=edit&amp;id=185" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<textarea class="edit" name="news_content" id="news_content" rows="30" cols="32" style="width:95%;">{$news_content}</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     CKEDITOR.replace( 'news_content' )
</script>
<input type="submit" accesskey="s" value="Eintragen (Alt+S)" class="button">
</form>
```

It is loaded correctly and I can use the editor to make any changes. However, when submitting the form using a normal submit button (no AJAX or JS at all here), there is no entry "news_content" in the $_POST array, nor is there any other element containing the data at all.

How can I make use of the content after submitting the form using a normal submit button?

Thanks in advance and best regards
Daniel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to run a function to update the actual form field, I had the same issue let me find my code. The actual form data doesn't get updated until you run a function to move the CKEditor data into the form field.

```
function updateAllMessageForms()
{
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that there is no way to simply "instruct" CKEditor to sync the data to the actual textarea while typing? So I have to update these update function before sending the formular?

Comment: You could attach this event on a keydown or keyup event, but yes just call this function before sending.

Comment: @vishalshah glad to help

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
if( $('.ckeditor').length > 0){
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            $('#' + instance).val(CKEDITOR.instances[instance].getData());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem in jquery ui dialog. this code has worked for me:

```
    function updateAllMessageForms(){
         for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
             CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor does do this for you automatically, as far as I know. I ran into the same problem, my POST variable for the textarea was blank. Turned out I had an error in my javascript onsubmit function that did validation. The javascript would error out and the form would be submitted, but the CKEditor code to populate the original textarea would not fire, due to that error.

I looked around in the source code, I think this updates the original textarea on submit:

```
// Integrate with form submit.
if ( editor.config.autoUpdateElementJquery && $element.is( 'textarea' ) && $( element.form ).length ) {
    var onSubmit = function() {
        $element.ckeditor( function() {
                editor.updateElement();
        } );
    };

    // Bind to submit event.
    $( element.form ).submit( onSubmit );

    // Bind to form-pre-serialize from jQuery Forms plugin.
    $( element.form ).bind( 'form-pre-serialize', onSubmit );

    // Unbind when editor destroyed.
    $element.bind( 'destroy.ckeditor', function() {
        $( element.form ).unbind( 'submit', onSubmit );
        $( element.form ).unbind( 'form-pre-serialize', onSubmit );
    } );
}
```